# batch compare two folders return all files that are not in another folder

Tags: batch-file, copy, xcopy

I tried this answer. Didn't work.

[Batch file compare two folders return files that aren't in one folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16341468/batch-file-compare-two-folders-return-files-that-arent-in-one-folder)

I want to update my Dropbox folder to local F drive. I compared the difference. Both have over 113k of files but some 400 files in F:\Dropbox\ are missing.

How can I check the missing files in F drive.

```
C:\User\Dropbox\
F:\Dropbox\
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16341468/batch-file-compare-two-folders-return-files-that-arent-in-one-folder I used this code but it didnt work..-.

Comment: "It didn't work" is quite a vague description - please be more specific! Anyway, just as an idea: what about `robocopy` with the `/L` switch (so it does not copy but lists what would be copied) and checking for so-called lonely (present in source only) and extra (present in destination only) items only? perhaps the `/V`, `/X` options and the `/XC`, `/XN`, `/XO` filters could be useful as well...